# Документация по классам java в стиле man

Tags: java, linux

Есть ли такая утилита как man в Линуксе, чтобы можно было читать мануал по классам(например Thread)

Comment: По Java  есть чудесная документация онлайн. Чем она не устраивает?

Comment: @Streletz интернет в 5 кбит/с))

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html Можно скачать

Comment: Есть ещё такая штука: https://zealdocs.org/